# ngFor with index from an object which contains an object which have a list that needs indexing?

Tags: angular, indexing, ngfor

I tried listing it like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index;" [attr.data-index]="i">
<td>{{item.grouporganizationunit.organizationunitlist[i].organizationunits.name}}</td>
```

but the console reports an error saying :

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'organizationunitlist' of undefined*

but my data have organizationunitlist and its not undefined , here's the log of data as prntscr 
http://prntscr.com/hyggpp

What am i doing wrong ? I check similar articles but i think my case is unique cuz i have object in an object who haves a list .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is case sensitive, another error is `.organizationunits.name`, you just need `organizationUnitList[i].name`. The following should work:

```
<td>{{item.groupOrganizationUnit.organizationUnitList[i].name}}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you , i didnt know that , and for the name i would find out but thanks for that too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you make mistake here

`item.grouporganizationunit.organizationunitlist[i].organizationunits.name`

Try out this one

```
item.grouporganizationunit.organizationunitlist[i].name
```